# Does ansible support modules written in Go?

Tags: go, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template, ansible-role

Ansible supports custom modules written in Python .

For execution types which are **not** local( local mean `connection: local` & `hosts: localhost`), ansible `ssh`'s python packages to remote node, for every play.

---

1. Does ansible support writing modules in Go?
2. if yes, can these modules be *remote execution type*? Because Go artifacts are binary artifacts.

Comment: github.com/vrutkovs/golang-modules-in-ansible

Answer (score 4):

Tasks are implemented using modules. Most modules are written in Python, but you can use another language if you wish.

From the [*Building A Simple Module*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html) guide, it states:

> We are going to use Python here but any language is possible. Only File I/O and outputting to standard out are required. So, bash, C++, clojure, Python, Ruby, whatever you want is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write Ansible modules in Go and run a binary in a remote host. Per [Get Yourself GOing with Ansible](https://codeburst.io/get-yourself-going-with-ansible-60ca623bf4):

> There are at least four different ways that you can run a Go program
> from Ansible. You can either:
>
> 1. Install Go and run your Go code with the go run command from Ansible.
> 2. Cross compile your Go code for different platforms before execution. Then call the proper binary from Ansible, based on the
>    facts you collect from the host.
> 3. Run your Go code or compiled binary from a container with the containers.podman collection.
> 4. Create an RPM package of your Go code with something like NFPM and install it in the system of the target host. You can then call it with
>    Ansible modules shell or command.